# How to install Cedar Siding at Gable (Shed)?

Tags: siding, shed

Hi I have a 11/12 pitch roof, and getting ready to install the cedar shingle siding at the Gables only (The single pieces, I think called cedar shakes). I have never done this, and I have seen a few Bob Villa videos over on YouTube. I get the gist of installing them straight across, but when you get to the soffit and peak, I am confused on how to end it. Do you generally nail it here exposing the nails? Or do you nail it and put some sort of trim around it to cover the nails..

Tips:
Btw, this is on a shed, and I have 30 roofing paper to put under it. Is this good? Or should it be Tyvek. It will be going over OSB sheathing. 
Also, I will have an octagon window up there at the peak, I assume the trim goes on first and shingles cut around it? Is a utility knife best to cut these or miter saw?

Thanks!

Comment: How long are the shakes? 18" 20" or 24"? Do you already know what the exposure you need to set the shakes at?

Comment: @Jack, I haven't purchased them yet but I assume it will be 18".  As far as exposure, if 18" looks like  8 1/2 inches of exposure..